# $_GET not working on my php file

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, web, get

I have a url link that has value of the id and process when clicked.
code:

```
<?php
 <a href='settoActive.php?id=".$row['id']."&process=actives' style='font-size:15px;' name='active' value=".$row['id']." class='btn btn-info' />ACTIVE</a>
?>

<a href='settoActive.php?id=".$row['id']."&process=inactive' style='font-size:15px;' name='active' value=".$row['id']." class='btn btn-info' />inactive</a>
```

and this is where the page will be redirected to:

```
<?php

$value = $_GET['process'];

echo "<script> alert(".$value.");</script> ";


if($_GET['proc']="actives"){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('10.237.2.152','root','c0k3float','monitoring');
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE  Shipment_Target SET status='Active' where id=".$id."  ") or mysqli0;


echo "<script>alert('Activessss!');  </script>";
//location.replace('addmodel.php')

}

if($_GET['process']="inactive"){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('10.237.2.152','root','c0k3float','monitoring');
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE  Shipment_Target SET status='Inactive' where id=".$id."  ") or mysqli0;


echo "<script>alert('Inactive!'); </script>";
}

// location.replace('addmodel.php')



?>
```

The problem is the 2 if condition trigger and why it is triggering at the same time?

Comment: `=` assigns variables, `==` compares.

Comment: I think there is some issues in the href, please check with print_r($_REQUEST)

Comment: also just a bit of poi `$_GET['proc']="actives"` <-- really `'proc'` not `process?

Comment: you should use `if($_GET['process']=="actives")` instead of `if($_GET['proc']="actives")`

Comment: i forgot to renamed it but still same outcome

Comment: @Qirel, you solved it. Thanks! Im feeling a bit tired my brain is malfunctioning haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 mistakes noticed... 2 places '==' operator and 1 place GET variable name 'process'.

```
$value = $_GET['process'];

echo "<script> alert(".$value.");</script> ";


if($_GET['process']=="actives"){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('10.237.2.152','root','c0k3float','monitoring');
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE  Shipment_Target SET status='Active' where id=".$id."  ") or mysqli0;


echo "<script>alert('Activessss!');  </script>";
//location.replace('addmodel.php')

}

if($_GET['process']=="inactive"){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('10.237.2.152','root','c0k3float','monitoring');
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE  Shipment_Target SET status='Inactive' where id=".$id."  ") or mysqli0;


echo "<script>alert('Inactive!'); </script>";
}

// location.replace('addmodel.php')



?>
```

Comment: Same answer as @Qirel

Comment: Yup... And the variable name also...

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the html code, try following code

```
<a href='settoActive.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&process=actives' style='font-size:15px;' name='active' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class='btn btn-info' />ACTIVE</a>

<a href='settoActive.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&process=inactive' style='font-size:15px;' name='active' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class='btn btn-info' />inactive</a>
```